# How to invalidate the sso access token after log in (logout from AWS)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sso, aws-iam-authenticator, aws-iam-identity-center, aws-iam-access-analyzer

I have a C# .net core application (Target framework - .NET 6.0) written based on the instructions given in the tutorials below , I am using AWS IAM Identity Center (SSO authentication - SSOAWSCredentials) to authenticate to AWS, I could successfully log in but I couldn't find a way to clear/invalidate the token (in another words, logout from AWS) I noticed a session token is stored in the local file system in ({UserProfile}.aws\sso\cache) and if I delete that manually then I need to authenticate again - but is there a way to officially invalidate the token?

Single sign-on (SSO) with the AWS SDK for .NET - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/sso.html